# Что предпочтительнее использовать jQuery или $

Tags: javascript, jquery

При работе с jQuery как лучше писать, например `jQuery.ajax()` или `$.ajax()`.
Ajax для примера, не важно, например `jQuery('.class')` или `$('.class')`?
С долларом оно вроде и удобнее, но попалась на глаза статья где указано что при второй записи (с $) могут быть конфликты.

Comment: на самом деле без разницы, так как это одно и то же. А для конфликтов есть [noconflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Про конфликты уже рассказали. А вот про решение - не очень. Для того, чтобы железно застолбить для себя знак $ используйте конструкцию

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Здесь можно использовать знак $ ничего не опасаясь
}
```

Идея в том, что при вызове обработчика `ready` первым параметром в него передается объект `jQuery`, вот мы его и принимаем в `$`

`jQuery.noConflict();` освобождает **глобальную** переменную `$` и после его вызова значение **глобальной** переменной `$` принимает то же значение, что имело до инициализации библиотеки `jQuery`. Соответственно эту функцию нужно вызывать, если переменная `$` у Вас инициализируется до старта `jQuery` и Вы хотите это значение сохранить

Comment: а `$.noConflict();` добавлять не нужно, как указано по предоставленной @Grundy ссылке https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/ ?

Comment: @DidMazay Расширил ответ

Answer (score 1):

И `$`, и `jQuery` являются ссылками на одну функцию, так что в контексте одной жиквери совершенно неважно что использовать. Но знак `$` интересный и короткий, удобно для использования в быту.
Но проблема в том, что [не только](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632041/what-javascript-libraries-are-known-to-use-the-global-dollar-sign-window) разработчики `jQuery` поняли Силу знака доллара и тоже используют его как интерфейс доступа к своим разработкам ([`Prototype`](http://www.prototypejs.org/), [`MooTools`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3Adollar), [`Zepto.JS`](http://zeptojs.com/) и т. д.).
Поэтому, если Вы используете несколько библиотек, который тоже используют `$`, позаботьтесь о том, чтобы избежать конфликта (передача в замыкание, `noConflict` в библиотеках или же использование... товарных переменных: `jQuery`, например, эту переменную вряд ли кто займёт).